# Calabash ios real device connection

Tags: calabash-ios

I am working on calabash .I am able to run the script on simulator.When I run on real device Connection refused error message is displayed.Due to security policy phone and mac are not connected to same network.Is it mandatory for the phone and mac to be in same network to run calabash

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes. It is necessary for the Mac and the mobile device to be on the same network. Calabash executes its commands by communicating with the test server that is running on the device via network calls.

If you'd like to run on physical devices, I'm afraid your only option is to communicate the issue to your security team and see if they are able to provide you with a solution.